# TextField multiline + wrap get text height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text

I have a TextField with multiline and word wrap enabled, and a fixed width. I want to calculate the total height of the text inside it.

I tried using `TextField.textHeight`, but that gives me the height of one line. Because of the wrapping, I can't easily calculate the number of lines to multiply it with the line height. `TextField.height` just gives me the fixed, default height of the field, 100 pixels.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be a mistake in your code, since textHeight should return your TextField height , not just one line height.

Comment: Well maybe I had something wrong in my code, it's ok now though. Can't really remember how or when I fixed it.

Comment: TextField height is actually (textHeight + 4).  The TextField includes a 2px gutter around the text, so the TextField's height will automatically be adjusted to textHeight + (2px top gutter) + (2px bottom gutter) if autoSize is anything other than TextFieldAutoSize.NONE.  See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize  Setting wordWrap to true will cause horizontal auto-resizing to stop, but it will still auto-resize vertically.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you include wordWrap

this traces txt.textHeight = 135

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = new Bauhaus ().fontName;

var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.embedFonts = true;
txt.multiline = true;
txt.defaultTextFormat = format;
txt.wordWrap = true;
txt.width = 100;
txt.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi metus diam, condimentum sagittis rutrum vitae, vehicula et velit.";
addChild(txt);

trace("txt.textHeight "+txt.textHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from looking at [Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html), and this [tip](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?442282-number-of-lines-in-a-text-field).

Both of the following work perfectly for me with single-line, multi-line word-wrap (just text wrap, and \n), and multi-line no word wrap (just \n).

Short assumptive version (don't use this):

```
var totalLines = textField.bottomScrollV - textField.scrollV + textField.maxScrollV;
var metrics    = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
var gutter     = 2;
var actualHeight = (metrics.ascent + metrics.descent) * totalLines + (totalLines - 1) * metrics.leading + 2 * gutter;
```

Longer better version where lines have differing metrics (use this):

```
var gutter  = 2;
var totalLines = textField.bottomScrollV - textField.scrollV + textField.maxScrollV;

var actualHeight = 0;
var prevLeading = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < totalLines; i += 1)
{
    var metrics = textField.getLineMetrics(i);
    actualHeight += metrics.ascent + metrics.descent + prevLeading;
    prevLeading = metrics.leading;
}
actualHeight += 2 * gutter;
```

For a single line test with an inline image where textField height gives me 32, textHeight gives me 39, the calculated height (actualHeight above) is 34. For a multi-line test where height is 97.20, textHeight is 23.79, actualHeight is 97.15. This actual height includes the gutter on both sides, but strips out the trailing leading if there is any.